# Position fixed not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I applied position:fixed to my site-footer, it's working in Firefox, but in Chrome it's not fixed bottom. Can you please give me some advice?

```
.site-footer { 
background-color: #231F20;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px; 
}

<footer id="test" class="site-footer col-md-12">
    <div class="site-info">
        <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="/contact" class="btn btn-contact">Contact</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-about">Terms</a>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>.<br />

        </div>          
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
</footer>
```

I really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Must be something else - the code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Uyxk9/

Comment: Looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/K9VvP/

Comment: i see you are using bootstrap with this, maybe there is a !important tag on one of bootstraps' styles? you can see in the element inspector whether or not one of the styles is overwritten.

Comment: It looks fine in Chrome. Did you set `html, body { height: 100%; }`?

Comment: In Chrome it's not fixed bottom, it's fixed right after the colored divs.

Comment: That should work, does the class "col-md-12" or id "test" have a position relative on them?

Comment: Try right clicking and inspect the element using chrome and see if the fixed is being over-riden by something else

Comment: Use styling with `id` that should override classes `#test { background-color: #231F20; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 30px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; }`

Comment: Yes, col-md-12, has position relative inside.

Comment: What do you see if you inspect the elementin Google Chrome? (F12 or right click over the element and ispect element)

Comment: Either remove that or make you're css overwrite it i.e add !important to position:fixed or change your css selector to footer.site-footer{}

Comment: Nothing worked. Can i post the link to the website so you can have a look?

Comment: I fixed. The class was good but there was a missing closing </div> from another page which caused this. Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a collision with the bootstrap classes. Maybe you can add

```
position: fixed !important;
```

in the css to overwrite bootstraps styling

Comment: I added !important, but this didn't fixed the problem.